# Javascript simultaneously calling async endpoints

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm trying to implement asynchronous endpoints (.NET C#) in order to call them with javascript / ajax. The basic idea is to split the requests (>2 at the same time) in multiple threads, so that the user gets response individually from every call and the execution-time of each request corresponds to the actual calculating (or waiting) time.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Call1()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var res = await client.GetAsync("http://httpbin.org/delay/3"); // Takes 3 seconds

    return View("~/Views/Dashboard/Test.cshtml");
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Call2()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var res = await client.GetAsync("http://httpbin.org/delay/2"); // Takes 2 seconds

    return View("~/Views/Dashboard/Test.cshtml");
}
```

Let's assume the browser requests the methods Call1 und Call2 at the same time. Right now it takes approximately 5 seconds until both calls terminate (Call1 (3sec) + Call2 (2sec)). As far as I understand, this means that .NET handles them synchronous and waits Call1 to end before handling Call2, although they were called at the same time with async methods. That's not what I want.

[request times call1 / call2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz6XW.png)

I want to achieve the same result with multiple methods as shown in the following method which correctly only takes 3 seconds, although both services (3sec + 2sec) are called:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Delay()
{
    var client1 = new HttpClient();
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> async1 = client1.GetAsync("http://httpbin.org/delay/3");

    var client2 = new HttpClient();
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> async2 = client2.GetAsync("http://httpbin.org/delay/2");

    HttpResponseMessage result1 = await async1;
    HttpResponseMessage result2 = await async2;

    return View("~/Views/Dashboard/Test.cshtml");
}
```

Is it possible not to block other threads and handle several methods at the same time?

Thank you for your help.
vill

Comment: "As far as I understand, this means that .NET handles them synchronous and waits Call1 to end before handling Call2, although they were called at the same time with async methods" don't think this is correct

Comment: [How to write a C# Parallel.ForEach Loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @user5226582: Can't use Parallel-Class, because I need the logic separated in multiple methods.

Comment: @AnkitVijay: So you have any idea why the second call waits the first to end?

Comment: I don't think the second call does not wait for the first. Can see the time it took for result1 and then result2? It should be 3 and 2 respectively. The Test.cshtml view should come after 3 + 2 =  5 seconds. I post answer to which should help understand.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it takes 5 seconds is because you are wait for result1 first and then for result2. Try and modify your code to create a list of tasks and then await all the tasks using `Task.WhenAll`. Read more about `Task.WhenAll` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160384(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Delay()
{
    var tasks= new List<Task>();

    var client1 = new HttpClient();
    tasks.Add(client1.GetAsync("http://httpbin.org/delay/3"));

    var client2 = new HttpClient();
    tasks.Add(client2.GetAsync("http://httpbin.org/delay/3"));

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return View("~/Views/Dashboard/Test.cshtml");
```

}